# Why does Application.DispatcherUnhandledException prematurely catch exceptions from FrameworkElement.FindResource?

Tags: c#, wpf, exception

I have created a new WPF app and have this in my MainWindow:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Application.Current.DispatcherUnhandledException += (sender, args) =>
        {
            // Handle the event to keep the UI thread alive.
            args.Handled = true;
            MessageBox.Show("D");
        };

        try
        {
            Style style = FindResource("MyStyle") as Style; // This will throw a ResourceReferenceKeyNotFoundException
            MessageBox.Show("A");
        }
        catch (ResourceReferenceKeyNotFoundException exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("B");
        }

        MessageBox.Show("C");
    }
}
```

Note that "MyStyle" does NOT exist.

When I run the application I would expect to see popups: B, C.  But when I run my app I get popups: D, A, C.
When the exception is thrown, the `application.DispatcherUnhandledException` callback is fired (logs "D"). Then it returns to the UI thread ready to log "A".

Why does the `application.DispatcherUnhandledException` get called? If I change my main window code to manually throw the `ResourceReferenceKeyNotFoundException` i.e.

```
try
{
    throw new ResourceReferenceKeyNotFoundException();
    MessageBox.Show("A");
}
catch (ResourceReferenceKeyNotFoundException exception)
{
    MessageBox.Show("B");
}
```

Then I see popups "B,C" (which I originally expected). So it seems like there is special handling in `FindResource` to have the exception be prematurely treated as an unhandled exception.

Comment: Yes, [shenanigans are going on](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/MS/Internal/Helper.cs,46).  Hard to guess why this was considered useful, perhaps to avoid xaml mistakes from getting swallowed silently.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by @HansPassant, the framework doesn't throw the exception the way you expect.

I would encourage you to use the `TryFindResource` method and check for a return value. You can then throw the exception yourself (or simply display the `MessageBox` or what whatever you want to do without catching an exception):

```
Application.Current.DispatcherUnhandledException += (sender, args) =>
{
    // Handle the event to keep the UI thread alive.
    args.Handled = true;
    MessageBox.Show("D");
};

try
{
    Style style = TryFindResource("MyStyle") as Style;
    if (style == null)
        throw new ResourceReferenceKeyNotFoundException();
    MessageBox.Show("A");
}
catch (ResourceReferenceKeyNotFoundException exception)
{
    MessageBox.Show("B");
}

MessageBox.Show("C");
```

Comment: Yes, thankyou for the suggested workaround. But I am more interested in why this happens.

Comment: Then read the first sentence of my answer again?